# One domain, 2 sessions

Tags: coldfusion

I just figured out that if I go to

```
myDomain.com 
www.myDomain.com
```

it has two separate sessions.

Is there a setting Adobe ColdFusion 10 to make this a single session?

Comment: Wouldn't it be grant if the goit who voted to close this actually explained why? That might be helpful. As it is... not so much.

Comment: are you actually using both domains?

Comment: I don't need both.  Should I turn one off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off `setClientcookies` in Application.cfc and set `CFID` & `CFSESSION` cookie using `<cfcookie>` (or `<cfheader>` if u run into domain= bug) yourself onSessionStart with `domain=myDomain.com` and httponly

Comment: Urgh. That seems a bit ham-fisted, Henry. Can one not simply turn `setDomainCookies` on? (ref: https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Application+variables)

Comment: this.setDomainCookies = 'yes'; didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: The Muse talked about it in 2006 with [Maintaining Your Session Across Sub Domains](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2006/7/28/sessions.and.subdomains).

Comment: @AdamCameron have you tried it?  Does it work now?  I believe we tried that as well but it doesn't work somehow therefore we went with the set cookie ourselves @ onSessionStart approach.  If it indeed works, please post your answer?

Comment: @Henry Nope, not tried it, just saw the setting when investigating your answer. It seems there was a bug with this (as I guess you know), but also it was supposedly fixed in updater 14?

Comment: Version 10,0,15,292620. But now that I know what was causing the problem, I'll just be careful not to allow it.

Answer (score 1):

This is said to be fixed finally in update 5 of CF11. See the "bugs fixed" document linked to from https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-11-update-5.html, which has a link to the bug report above and indicates it's resolved. Sadly, there's no mention of it in the CF10 bugs fixed though. That would be a shame if it was happening in 10 but not fixed in it.